# Cant authenticate Pep Proxy user generated in Horizon when starting Pep proxy

Tags: proxy, fiware, keystone

I created pep proxy user in Horizon.

```
Username:
pep_proxy_4ac90a28a7e0465caf0a9f32998ab47b
Password:
##################
```

And than i changed config.js of PEP proxy:

```
config.username = 'pep-proxy-aadd736bf4ea4739bd3bfe2cac4178c0';
config.password = '##################';
```

And when i start pep proxy i get this error:

```
ERROR: Server - Error in keystone communication {"error": {"message":
 "The request you have made requires authentication.",
 "code": 401, "title": "Unauthorized"}}
```

Can you help me with this.What might be the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that even though this user is created via Horizon it isn't granted any assignment in default domain. 
I just ran

```
curl -v -s -X PUT     -H "X-Auth-Token: ............................"
 -H "Content-type: application/json"
 http://192.168.4.180:5000/v3/domains/default/users/pep-proxy-aadd736bf4ea4739bd3bfe2cac4178c0/roles/4475dadfface4582ba8c7ab0c6f48d1c
```

where '4475dadfface4582ba8c7ab0c6f48d1c' is id of admin role.